# SQL - select max of datetime by day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

Using the below example, I want to get a count of records grouped by Person and Product, for each day.

The example on the left is the data in the SQL Server 2008 database.  The data on the right is my desired query result.

I could just substring off the time portion of the date values, then just do a Group By... but ideally the Max(date) would contain the full timestamp...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.person, t.product, count(*) as cnt, max(t.date) as date
from table t
group by t.person, t.product, cast(t.date as date);
```

Comment: that works, I've never done a cast in a group by... or a cast with the max function... thank you :) . .   Just curious for future reference, why was the "MAX" tag on the post removed?

Comment: @adam . . . The database tags seem more useful and some of the tags needed to be removed.